# C with postgres, get all rows and put then into a html table

Tags: c, database, postgresql, resultset

i have a postgres database and a program in C that connects with this table

now i need to get all the results from this table and create a html file with the data.

this is my table

```
=> select * from users;

 id_user | first_name  |  last_name  |       address        |      city       |      phone
---------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+-----------------+------------------
       1 |  James      |  Butt       |  6649 N Blue Gum St  |  New Orleans    |  504-621-8927
       2 |  Josephine  |  Darakjy    |  4 B Blue Ridge Blvd |  Brighton       |  810-292-9388
       4 |  Lenna      |  Paprocki   |  639 Main St         |  Anchorage      |  907-385-4412
```

For now i have a loop

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    char createCommand[200];
    sprintf(createCommand,
            "%s %d %s %d %s", "select * from users limit ", i, "offset ", i , ";");
    doSQL(conn, createCommand);
}

void doSQL(PGconn *conn, char *command)
{
    PGresult *result;

    printf("%s\n", command);

    result = PQexec(conn, command);
    printf("status is     : %s\n", PQresStatus(PQresultStatus(result)));
    printf("#rows affected: %s\n", PQcmdTuples(result));
    printf("result message: %s\n", PQresultErrorMessage(result));

    switch(PQresultStatus(result))
    {
        case PGRES_TUPLES_OK:
            int n = 0, m = 0;
            int nrows   = PQntuples(result);
            int nfields = PQnfields(result);
            printf("number of rows returned   = %d\n", nrows);
            printf("number of fields returned = %d\n", nfields);
            for(m = 0; m < nrows; m++)
            {
                for(n = 0; n < nfields; n++)
                    printf(" %s = %s", PQfname(result, n),PQgetvalue(result,m,n));
                printf("\n");
            }
    }
    PQclear(result);
}
```

but doSQL is a void function so i wanted to create a structure to put the values from db but i don't know how to do it exactly.

Comment: You need a clear problem statement - what works, what doesn't work, what you've tried and what you've learned from your debugging efforts.

Comment: You say *doSQL is a void function*. The real problem is not far: you must find a way to return values from `doSQL`. You should contemplate returning newly allocated arrays that should be free-ed by caller after use. But currently this post is unclear according to SO rules...